# Can't get file to save as .mp4 using Matplotlib's .save() in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am working on recreating this code to learn how to animate football plays using the 2021 bigdatabowl data files.

https://www.kaggle.com/ar2017/nfl-big-data-bowl-2021-animating-players-movement

But for some reason, I can't recreate this chunk:

```
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=10)
anim.save('animation_notrail.mp4', writer=writer)
```

I get the error:

```
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-20-2f3fc93131d5> in <module>
>      2 writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=10)
>      3 #print(writer)
> ----> 4 anim.save('animation_notrail.mp4', writer=writer)

>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in save(self, filename, writer, fps, dpi, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata, extra_anim, savefig_kwargs, progress_callback)
>   1137         # callback a no-op; canvas.manager = None prevents resizing the GUI
>   1138         # widget (both are likewise done in savefig()).
> -> 1139         with mpl.rc_context({'savefig.bbox': None}), \
>   1140              writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi), \
>   1141              cbook._setattr_cm(self._fig.canvas,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
>    111         del self.args, self.kwds, self.func
>    112         try:
> --> 113             return next(self.gen)
>    114         except StopIteration:
>    115             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in saving(self, fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
>    247         """
>    248         # This particular sequence is what contextlib.contextmanager wants
> --> 249         self.setup(fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
>    250         try:
>    251             yield self
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in setup(self, fig, outfile, dpi)
>    336         # Run here so that grab_frame() can write the data to a pipe. This
>    337         # eliminates the need for temp files.
> --> 338         self._run()
>    339 
>    340     def _run(self):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in _run(self)
>    346                   cbook._pformat_subprocess(command))
>    347         PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
> --> 348         self._proc = subprocess.Popen(
>    349             command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
>    350             creationflags=subprocess_creation_flags)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout,  stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
>    856                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
>    857 
> --> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
>    860                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
>   1309             # Start the process
>   1310             try:
> -> 1311                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
>   1312                                          # no special security
>   1313                                          None, None,
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I do print the writer function I get:

```
print(writer)
```

<matplotlib.animation.FFMpegWriter object at 0x000001A759E25D00>

So I know that it is creating the object for me. I believe the problem is with  the  anim.save() function.

I have made an empty file with the same filename in the same folder I am working in, hoping it would fix the problem but it didn't. I also tried an alternative I found, but I got the same error.

```
f = r"C:/Users/brigh/Documents/PythonVS/BigDataBowl/filesav.mp4" 
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=10)
anim.save(f, writer=writer)


f = r"C:/Users/brigh/Documents/PythonVS/BigDataBowl/filesav.mp4" 
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=10)
anim.save(f, writer=writer)
```

For reference I  am using VScode with the JupyterNotebook Extension using Python 3.8.8 64-bit ('base':conda)

Comment: Do you have `ffmpeg` installed?  The FFMpegWriter function is a thin wrapper that calls the `ffmpeg` command line tool to do the work.  It needs to be able to find the command line tool.

Comment: [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) - did you install it? It is not Python module so you have to download and install it manually.

Comment: No, I didn't. That should fix the problem, that makes total sense. Thank you!